# How to build armv8 and x86_64 crosswalk runtime while applying it as cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-runtime

Basically, there are armeabi-v7a and x86 built under the following path.

> \android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\org.xwalk\xwalk_core_library\16.45.421.19\jni\

I'd like to know how can I build arm64-v8a and x86_64 under this path.

I run `cordova build android` to build the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview#160-march-11-2016) readme you can use

```
cordova build android --xwalk64bit
```